# Actionscript 3: Converting bytearray to PNG and display on the scene

Tags: actionscript-3, png, arrays

I'm getting getting a PNG image stored in SQL through a WCF get call. The image is encoded as a base64 string and delivered to my AS3 code. I need to extract the image from the data and show it on the scene.
Among other things, I have also tried this...

```
    var imgArray:ByteArray = Base64.decodeToByteArray(responseXML.ImageObject);
var myRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(100,100,200,200);
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(200,200,true,0xAAAAAAAA);
bmd.setPixels(myRect, imgArray);
var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd,"auto",true);
this.addChild(image);
```

but to no avail.
HELP!

Comment: I didn't get an error. I just didn't get the image on my stage. I solved the issue. The solution is given below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why don't you use a loader and loadbytes?  It's native.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoad)
loader.loadbytes(byteArray);

private function handleLoad(e:Event):void {
  var loader:Loader = e.currentTarget as Loader;
  // removelistener,etc

  trace(loader.content as Bitmap);
}
```

The problem with your code is that PNG is compressed, bitmap is uncompressed.

Comment: You should mark this as the "answer".  And delete your "answer".

Comment: @ansiart, I didn't have sufficient reps to do that back then... but now I do. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I used DanielH's input and got the image to load on my stage. Here is what I did in the event handler function...

```
    function ImageLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(imageLoader.ImageLoader.width,imageLoader.ImageLoader.height,true, 0xFFFFFF);
        bmd.draw(imageLoader.ImageLoader);
        var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd,"auto",true);
        image.width=40;
        image.height=40;
        if(!CheckAndStoreImageIDKey(imageLoader.ImageID))
        {
            Images[imageLoader.ImageID] = image;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [PNGDecoder (http://www.ionsden.com/content/pngdecoder)](http://www.ionsden.com/content/pngdecoder)

```
import ion.utils.png.PNGDecoder;

var bmd:BitmapData = PNGDecoder.decodeImage(imgArray);
```

Comment: I got to know that AS3-Flash supports PNG, JPEG and GIF formats by default. So it was not necessary to use a PNG decoder.
Thanks for your inputs though. I will evaluate use of PNGDecoder also.